# How to quit nc once input is done?

Tags: netcat

I use the followng `netcat`.

```
$  netcat --version 
netcat (The GNU Netcat) 0.7.1
Copyright (C) 2002 - 2003  Giovanni Giacobbi

This program comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
You may redistribute copies of this program under the terms of
the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.

Original idea and design by Avian Research <hobbit@avian.org>,
Written by Giovanni Giacobbi <giovanni@giacobbi.net>.
```

In the following example, `netcat` will hang there.

```
sed 's/$/\r/g' <<EOF | netcat -v httpbin.org 80
GET /get HTTP/1.1
Host:httpbin.org

EOF
```

The following URL is for the same question, but I am not sure which flavor of `netcat` it is as I don't find the `-q` option in `netcat` that I use.

https://serverfault.com/questions/512722/automatically-close-netcat-connection

Does anybody know how to quit `netcat` once the input is done?

Comment: Give socat a try, I used it last week and it closed automatically when input ended

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever mechanism you would normally use to indicate an end-of-input condition in a terminal window.  On a Linux/Unix system you would do that by typing whatever is defined to be the `eof` character shown in the output of a `stty -a` command.  Traditionally the `eof` character is Control-D.  On Windows you would type Control-Z followed by Enter.

Comment: I don't want to type the character. I'd like `netcat` terminate automatically.